# Timeout expired during select request using NHibernate

Tags: .net, sql-server, nhibernate, timeout

I use NHibernate in my project. Sometimes some diferent request to different table fail with `GenericADOException` which wraps inside `SqlException: Timeout expired.`

Example (there is index on ObjectId)

> NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not execute query [
> select user_15f5e0_.Id as col_0_0_, user_15f5e0_.ObjectId as col_1_0_,
> user_15f5e0_.TypeName as col_2_0_, user_15f5e0_.VulnerabilityLevel as
> col_3_0_, user_15f5e0_.DisplayName as col_4_0_, user_15f5e0_.UserName
> as col_5_0_ from [User] user_15f5e0_ where user_15f5e0_.ObjectId in
> (@p0 , @p1 , @p2 , @p3 , @p4 , @p5 ) ]
>
> --> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is
> not responding.
>
> ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

It's only one request via WebApi, without different activitis in other threads. According to logs there are no opend transactions. I thought that main reason was not commited transaction, but these exceptions occure undeterminated whithout any "write" activity.

Can anyone explain what can be the main reason of this errors?

Comment: How long does it take, and why do you expect that duration to be excessive? You mention "logs", but are those just from that program, or might there be other applications using the database?

Comment: @OskarBerggren This behavior begins at indefinite times and takes till application restart. Moreover sometimes requests can be executed without any errors. Yes, this log is from one service. I mean "logs" as a lot of items in one log-file. The data base is always used by one instance of one application

Comment: @lomomike did you find anything? I´m facing that same behavior every once in a while.

Comment: @LuizHenriqueMartinsLinsRol Unfortunately no. It was peridical problem, wich reprodeced very seldom.

Comment: Has someone solve this yet? I'm having the same issue and it fires randomly.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps:

To me It turned out to be an issue related to not closing transactions properly (not calling Dispose, nor eclosed by a "using" block).